# RVM is trying to use the wrong Ruby version

Tags: ruby, rvm, rvmrc

I have installed Ruby 1.9.3-p327 and I can use it and my .rvmrc file contains the following:

`rvm use ruby-1.9.3`

But when I go to the project directory, an error occurs:

> ruby-1.9.3-p362 is not installed.
>
> To install do: 'rvm install ruby-1.9.3-p362'`

Why it happens? I do not want to use p362, i need p327 and I have installed it!

Maybe it's because I had installed p362 before and deleted it wrong somehow? I used `rvm remove 1.9.3-p362`. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current RVM considers `Ruby 1.9.3` and `Ruby 1.9.3-p362` equivalent. Future revisions of RVM will assume another value. It assumes you mean the most recent/highest number revision known to it for potential installation, which isn't based on what is installed. You can test this by `rvm install 1.9.3` which will install `1.9.3-p362` currently.

Instead try using `Ruby 1.9.3-p327` in your `.rvmrc` file.

Answer (score 1):

maybe there is a ".rvmrc" file in the folder that you are accessing, thus rvm will load the specified version automatically.

just remove that .rvmrc file or change that file to match your installed rvm ruby versions

Answer (score 0):

Run "rvm list" to see the list of Ruby installations that RVM knows about.   It is very likely that RVM is picking up configuration from someone unexpected.   Also, don't forget to look at the output of "rvm debug" this will 100% tell you EXACTLY where your Ruby installations are for RVM.

Good luck.